# How do I merge many similar tables?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012

I have many tables that all have identical structure and similar table names and am looking for a way to merge a few columns from them all into a new table with two additional columns: an auto-generated integer PK, and the name of the source table.  e.g.,

UniqueID SourceID, Xcoord, Ycoord, Zcoord, SourceTable

I managed to create a table containing a list of all the tables I want to use, but don't know what to do next.

```
SELECT [name]
INTO PointTables
FROM [Surveys].[sys].[tables]
where [name] like '%CoordDB'
```

Comment: you are getting table name by using sys.tables but what about columns join with sys.columns

Comment: How many tables do you have? When I faced a similar situation I used union operations and then inserted that query into a new table. In my case the two new columns were an identity column and a calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear about the problem.
Are the columns name of those tables are same?
You want to insert to the PointTables?

You can create the table:

```
create table PointTables(
UniqueID    int identity
, Xcoord    int
, Ycoord    int
, Zcoord    int
, SourceTable   varchar(50)
```

After that, you can insert table with help of sp_executesql command and concatenation

```
declare @command nvarchar(max) 
select @command = 'insert into PointTables(Xcoord,YCoord,ZCoord,SourceTable)
select [Xcoord],[YCoord],[Zcoord],'''+name+''' from '+name from sys.tables where name like '%CoordDB%'
execute sp_executesql @command
```

Comment: Thanks - this gets me close but only grabs the data from the first table it finds.  After searching around I found mention of cursors, but dont know how to use them yet.

Comment: Well, actually you can do some workaround with looping. Create a table that contain 2 columns: id and tablename. Id column is autoincrement, used for looping. Looping has better performance and easier syntax than cursor.

Comment: Thanks.  Performance will become an issue when I start working on real data, so I will try that on the next round.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Charlie Lukman was a good start but for some reason only worked on the first table.  I looked at several other posts and discovered cursors which allow you to work on one line at a time using a WHILE loop to build / concatenate several INSERT INTO commands.  While this works in my test of 5 tables, I am concerned about performance when I get to 100's or 1000's of tables.

```
declare @command nvarchar(max) 
declare @tblname varchar(50)
declare TableCursor Cursor
    FOR SELECT name FROM sys.tables where name like '%%DB_COORD'
SET @command = ''
OPEN TableCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @tblname

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN
        select @command =  @command + 'INSERT into MasterPoints(SourceID, Xcoord, Ycoord, Zcoord, PtCode, SourceTable)  SELECT UPTNUM, EAST, NORTH, ELEVATION, CODE,''' + @tblname + '''from "' + @tblname + '" '
        FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @tblname
    END
CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor

execute sp_executesql @command
```

SELECT distinct [SourceTable]
  FROM [Manifold].[dbo].[MasterPoints]